# how can I fix icons doesn't appear in the application

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MV9u.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD0ML.png)
I want fix `icons` drawer doesn't appear in my application in **flutter**? it just show message `icon` in screen down below in the picture.

```
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.phone,
                          size: 35,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please attach an image of the desired result for better understanding?

Comment: Could you please edit and post your question? Just take a picture and post a link. The link you gave in the answer is not accessible.

Comment: paste the entire contents of your pubspec.yaml,  you might have tampered with material there

Comment: try to add width and height for the Container. Compare with icon Size